# Clear memory being used by PHP

Tags: php, memory, phpunit

I'm running into an interesting problem.  I'm using PHPUnit, and my tests take more memory every single time I run them. Ie...

2.25 MB

2.5 MB

3.0 MB

3.5 MB
.......

Does anyone know how to clear out the memory that is being consumed, and can anyone advise me on exploring this in depth?  The immediate problem is that some of my larger tests are running out of memory, and simply continuing to increase the max memory allotment in PHP isn't good enough...I need to know why a PHPUnit test running from command line would have memory usage which "sticks around" between runs.

Comment: which version of PHPUnit are you using? and roughly what kind of code are you testing? Are you pushing tests to Travis CI?

Comment: PHPUnit 3.7.8-13-ged6eed8, testing a custom framework.  Not pushing tests to Travis CI.

Comment: TBH: 3.5MB isn't a lot. are these individual tests or you run them one after another using one PHP instance?

Comment: One of my tests went from consuming 100MB to consuming 500+MB after running it about 10 times.

Comment: I run an individual test from command line like this: phpunit tests/unit/Models/MyTest

Comment: roughly what's in the code if you're comfortable sharing?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20021/discussion-between-mauris-and-calvin-froedge)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calvin, as per discussed in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/20021), it was due to missing reset features.

When testing, we must ensure that the test environment is consistent so that we're able to get accurate results. Computing is Input/Output and hence we should use [Fixtures in PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/fixtures.html) to reset storage to prevent "memory leaks" like these.

Answer (score 28):

The memory increase has three to four reasons:

#### 1) PHPUnit collects code coverage data

There is nothing you can do about this except turn off code coverage.

#### 2) PHPUnit caches file tokens for code coverage

You can use `<phpunit cacheTokens="false">` in your PHPUnit xml. See the note about this in http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html#installing.upgrading

#### 3) PHPUnit doesn't properly clean up after itself

In its current implementation it keeps the test cases around because thats where the result data is stored. In the future this will be changed to be more efficent but for now it's how things works.

#### 4) Leading to "4": You need to clean up after your self too

Since the `TestCase` instances are keep around your member variables are kept around too.

Meaning you can save a lot of memory by using

```
public function tearDown() {
    unset($this->whatever);
}
```

but doing so is *very* tedious.

My suggestion is to have a base test class for all your TestCases and use this:

```
class MyBaseTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    protected function tearDown()
    {
        $refl = new \ReflectionObject($this);
        foreach ($refl->getProperties() as $prop) {
            if (!$prop->isStatic()
                && 0 !== strpos($prop->getDeclaringClass()->getName(), 'PHPUnit_')
                && $prop->getType()?->allowsNull() !== false
            ) {
                $prop->setAccessible(true);
                $prop->setValue($this, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will clean up after you in a nice, automated way.

(props for the snippet go to: http://kriswallsmith.net/post/18029585104/faster-phpunit)

---

PHPUnit can't do this in a backwards compatible way that wouldn't break people's projects so you have to add it for you own :)

Comment: You need to replace `'PHPUnit_'` by `'PHPUnit\\'` if you use PHPUnit 6.

Comment: Not only did this not work for me; I ran out of memory about 40% of the way in. Looks like it bombed on `$refl->getProperties()`; perhaps it got an inordinate number of properties in a test?

Answer (score 6):

The technical details behind PHPUnit's garbage collection have already been covered by @edorian and @mauris, but I wanted to add that PHPUnit (at least in version 3.7.21, which I'm running) gives you the ability to add the comment:

```
/**
 * @backupGlobals disabled
 */
class MyClassTests extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{}
```

Before adding the annotation, I was roughly doubling my memory usage on each run of my test suite, the last one hitting about 1100 MB. Now they're running at 15 MB.