# phpunit tests leak memory and mysql connections

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2, phpunit

I've run into problems with 'Too many connections' and 'memory exhausted' errors when running many tests. I've followed steps from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13551745/533209), including ensuring code coverage is disabled, setting `cacheTokens` to false, and adding the suggested `tearDown` method. I also upgraded to phpunit 4.7, but I still get an increasing memory usage for every test, and after a while, too many mysql connections.

Mysql: I've made sure that all references to the connection are nullified, but it seems that the connections are kept around anyway because the script is still running. One workaround I found was to set the connection timeout parameters to 3 seconds, but I don't know what kind of side effects that might have. So far, I've seen a few "MySQL server has gone away" messages

Here is my current `tearDown` method

```
    $sm = $this->getApplicationServiceLocator();
    $adapter = $sm->get('Adapter\Db');
    $adapter->getDriver()->getConnection()->disconnect();

    //reset zf2 app
    $this->reset();

    //remove phpunit instance variables
    $refl = new \ReflectionObject($this);
    foreach ($refl->getProperties() as $prop) {
        if (!$prop->isStatic() && 0 !== strpos($prop->getDeclaringClass()->getName(), 'PHPUnit_')) {
        //if (true) {
            $prop->setAccessible(true);
            $prop->setValue($this, null);
        }
    }
    parent::tearDown();
```

How can I ensure that memory and mysql connections are disposed of properly, so I can run more and more tests?